# Turn off automatic induction principle in Coq

Tags: coq, induction

I have defined a nested inductive data type and have defined a custom inductive principle for it. However, automated tactics from a library I'm using (specifically, DBLib for de Bruijn indices) expects induction is on the usual inductive principle. Since I never intend to use the originally-generated inductive principle, is there any way to either replace the automatically-generated principle? Or, if not, is there a way to temporarily turn off this automatic generation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using [`Elimination Schemes`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/proof-schemes.html#coq:opt.elimination-schemes) option. For instance,

```
Unset Elimination Schemes.
Inductive nat_tree : Set :=
| NNode' : nat -> list nat_tree -> nat_tree.
Set Elimination Schemes.
```

In addition, if you had a simpler (non-recursive) inductive type, you could have used the [`Variant`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#coq:cmd.variant) keyword to make Coq not generate the induction principles:

```
Variant foo : Type := Foo.
```